# PySide QTextEdit html table width

Tags: html, qt, pyqt, pyside, qtextedit

I am trying to set the width of my html table to acquire the total width of my `QTextEdit` by an inline stylesheet but the width of the table doesn't change. I've tried to give it values in the forms of percentages(%) and even pixels(px) but nothing changes.. Could you please have a look?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class MainWid(QtGui.QWidget):
    htmlTable = '''<table border="1" style="width:100%"> <!-- XXX Nothing happens!! -->
        <tr><th colspan="2">HEADER</th></tr>
        <tr><td>name</td><td>value</td></tr>
        <tr><td>name</td><td>value</td></tr>
    </table>'''
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWid, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initgui()

    def initgui(self):
        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        txt = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)

        lay.addWidget(txt)
        txt.setReadOnly(True)
        txt.setHtml(self.htmlTable)

        self.setLayout(lay)
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    wid = MainWid()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if this is what you are looking for:

```
htmlTable = ''' <table border="1" width="100%">
                    <tr><th colspan="2">HEADER</th></tr>
                    <tr><td>name</td><td>value</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>name</td><td>value</td></tr>
                </table>
            '''
```

Comment: nope, it isn't... the (%%) was left there by accident because I use string formating but it is not what causes the unwanted behavior.+1 for spotting the typo though.. I'll edit.

Comment: if replacing `style="width:100%"` with `width="100%"` doesn't resolve your issue, could you please find a way to show how exactly is it that you want your table to be displayed? see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cricobs/u8gEC/)